# Is an anti-derivative the "closed form" of numerical integration?

Tags: calculus

Context: I had been learning about summations prior to delving into calculus.

It sounds like numerical integration, for example, "summing" the little pieces under the $x^2$ curve where $x$ goes from $0$ to $n$:

$$
\int_0^n x^2dx
$$

Will then have a "closed form" aka anti-derivative of

$$
\frac{n^3}{3} + C
$$

Where $C$ is a translational constant might have been present in the original function. Is this a valid interpretation? As I understand it this is why the effort of finding anti-derivatives is worthwhile because you can get an exact answer and more quickly too.

Also, is this notation correct?

$$
\int_{x=0}^n x^2dx
$$

I.e. making an explicit "index of integration". Or am I thinking too discretely?

Comment: I think for the last one you should use $lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N} x_k^2 \Delta x$, since we should give information of the partition of $[0, n]$.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, for any continuous function $f$, the function $F(b)=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ will always be an anti-derivative of $f$. The constant $C$ in this context is a compensation for the fact that the lower bound $a$ of the integral is arbitrary and varying $a$ would lead to anti-detivatives $F(b)$ with a different added constant $C$. So the "translation" that you referred to is not about the original function but the integration bound. This is still not entirely true though, as for example when $f(x)=0$, the constant $C$ will have no real meaning through integration.

Comment: @EdwardH Thanks for your comment. So both, using my example above, $F(b) = \int_a^b x^2dx$ and (rewriting referring to $x$) $\frac{x^3}{3}$ would both be classed as anti-derivatives. One is just quicker than the other to calculate. I am just coming to grips with the terminology (e.g. integral, anti-derivative, primitive seeming to mean the same thing)